# Jenkins RBAC chart values for User permissions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rbac

Hi I Deployed Jenkins with helm chart values .

Currently using RBAC and working fine. Using below values in helm chart .

```
authorizationStrategy: |-
      roleBased:
        roles:
          global:
            - name: "Jenkins Admin"
              description: "Jenkins administrators"
              permissions:
                - "Overall/Administer"
              entries:
              - group:  "Jenkins – PRD Admin"
            - name: "DevOps"
              description: "DevOps Users"
              permissions:
                - "Overall/Read"
                - "Job/Create"
              entries:
              - group:  "Jenkins – DevOps"
```

I would like to give Admin permissions to a user instead of AD Group .
can anyone let me know how to  assign permissions to user  along with AD Groups